# Failed to create cuSolverDN instance

Tags: python, tensorflow

tensorflow version:1.12, cuda version:10.0

When I build my code, there is a error message:

```
2019-03-23 18:53:29.965772: I tensorflow/core/kernels/cuda_solvers.cc:159] Creating CudaSolver handles for stream 0x55c9d5a16320
2019-03-23 18:53:30.063068: F tensorflow/core/kernels/cuda_solvers.cc:94] Check failed: cusolverDnCreate(&cusolver_dn_handle) == CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS Failed to create cuSolverDN instance.
```

This problem occurred after I wrote code about distribution(from tensorflow-probability). Of course if I remove the code and compile again, there is nothing happened. 
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I used tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance

Comment: I used MultivariateNormalDiag instead of FullCovariance. Even though it is not exactly what I want, I could compile my code

Comment: Any luck on solving the issue?